# Weird use Date object

Tags: javascript, html

```
+ + new Date
```

**Output**

1429943200207

I saw this strange statement in our thirdparty plugin. I tried to break the logic but I can't. It returns the current time in ms as same as `new Date().getTime()`.

Is that an alternate way to return in current time ms?

How it works?

Comment: What's on the line before it?

Comment: @kojow7
return + + new Date + Math.random();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put unary `+` before a value, it is converted to a number. So

```
+ new Date
```

is equivalent to

```
Number(new Date)
```

And converting a `Date` to a number returns the time in milliseconds, so they're both equivalent to

```
(new Date).getTime()
```

I'm not sure why you have two `+`, though. Maybe the first one is part of a larger expression, like

```
"The timestamp is " + + new Date
```

Then the first `+` is for concatenation.

Comment: For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)